# VBA to Star Basic (OpenOffice), struggling

Tags: vba, migration, openoffice.org, openfiledialog

I have this task to convert recenntly written VBA code to OpenOffice version. I tried to launch it from OpenOffice, but it doesn't work (mostly "unsatisfied query..." error. I am now stuck on Open File Dialog, I can either use VBA compatible open file dialog as mine looks now like that (giving error):

```
FileToOpen = Application.GetOpenFilename("Please choose a file to import", "Excel Files *.dbf (*.dbf)")
```

I can also use OpenOffice file dialog box, but couldn't find any information on this.

Thanks in advance

Comment: have you tried a [converter?](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=Excel%20VBA%20to%20OpenOffice%20converter)

Comment: I have tried 2 converters I found, but none works properly.

Answer (score 1):

I'm confused on what you're asking, but if you're having trouble creating a file dialog box, this is VBA code that will do it for you. I think this is what you're asking, but I could be wrong.

```
    Private Sub cmdFileDialog_Click()

    ' This requires a reference to the Microsoft Office 11.0 Object Library.

    Dim fDialog As Office.FileDialog
    Dim varFile As Variant

    ' Clear the list box contents.
    Me.FileList.Value = ""

    ' Set up the File dialog box.
    Set fDialog = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFilePicker)
    With fDialog
    ' Change allowmultiselect to true if you want them to be able to select multiple files
    .AllowMultiSelect = False

    ' Set the title of the dialog box.
    .Title = "Select One or More Files"

    ' Clear out the current filters, and then add your own.
    .Filters.Clear
    .Filters.Add "All Files", "*.*"

    ' Show the dialog box. If the .Show method returns True, the
    ' user picked at least one file. If the .Show method returns
    ' False, the user clicked Cancel.
    If .Show = True Then
     ' Loop through each file that is selected and then add it to the list box.
     For Each varFile In .SelectedItems
        Me.FileList.Value = varFile
     Next
    Else
     MsgBox "You clicked Cancel in the file dialog box."
    End If
    End With
    End Sub
```

Comment: I think he is asking how to do that same thing in OpenOffice